# ScrollViewReader / scrollTo(_:anchor:) not working reliably

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, scrollviewreader

I've build a `ScrollView` which contains 0-3 images and a multiline text field in a `VStack`. I also added a `ScrollViewReader` inside the scrollview and use it to scroll to the bottom of the text field upon certain events (user starts typing, image collection changes).

The point is: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. When it does not work I realized, that when I scroll a little bit by hand and then try again (e.g. typing) it works.

Not sure if this is relevant, but `ImageOrPlaceholderComponent` first shows a placeholder as long as the image within `currentEntryImages` is nil, and the image after that (both states imply a change to `currentEntryImages` and should thus result in scrolling to the bottom of the text field).

```
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { scrollview in
                    VStack {
                        // Attached images.
                        AnyLayout(VStackLayout(spacing: 2.5)) {
                            ForEach(values: currentEntryImages) { entryImage in
                                ImageOrPlaceholderComponent(image: entryImage)
                                    .clipped()
                            }
                        }

                        // Text field for the entry with toolbar.
                        TextField("...", text: $entryDTO.text, axis: .vertical)
                            .id(entryTextFieldAnchor)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .padding()
                            .focused($mainTextFieldFocused)
                            .onAppear { mainTextFieldFocused = true }

                            // Scroll to the bottom of the text field, when the user is typing ...
                            .onChange(of: entryDTO.text) { _ in
                                withAnimation {
                                    scrollview.scrollTo(entryTextFieldAnchor, anchor: .bottom)
                                }
                            }

                            // ... or the entry images have changed.
                            .onChange(of: currentEntryImages) { _ in
                                withAnimation {
                                    scrollview.scrollTo(entryTextFieldAnchor, anchor: .bottom)
                                }
                            }
                    }
      
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `ScrollViewReader` goes on the outside of `ScrollView`, not inside

Comment: That true - thanks for the hint. But unfortunately it did not solve the issue. The behavior is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Found another hack, seems more solid than the rate-limiting one (leaving the answer as it is a quick and dirty solution that sometimes work)

Assuming the behavior we are seeing is some internal state breaking in ScrollView or ScrollViewReader, I came up with a way to "help" the internal state machine.

It's super hacky, but seems to work really well for me. The trick is to have two **different** empty views at the bottom of the scroll content, and then intermittently scroll to the bottom of each of them.

So my scroll content ends with:

```
Text("")
    .frame(height: 0.0)
    .id(2)
Text("")
    .frame(height: 0.0)
    .id(3)
```

These hacky views were better than `EmptyView()`'s in my tests. Again, treading black-box territory here, so will allow it :)

Then in your scrolling code you do this based on your own counting logic:

```
if (newStepCount % 3 == 0) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        proxy.scrollTo(newStepCount % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 3, anchor: .bottom)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Was facing a similar problem. While not a perfect solution I noticed that rate-limiting the scrollTo function solved the issue.

Once I updated, say, once every 5 times, it scrolled as should and didn't require manual scrolling first.

My guess is something breaks in the internal scrolling logic, and from what I could see ScrollViewReader doesn't expose anything to help us moderate the usage.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I'm currently struggling with another part of my app, but I will check this later!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it by having another marker at the top of the scrollview, and calling sequentially:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    reader.scrollTo(topID, anchor: .top)
    reader.scrollTo(bottomID, anchor: .bottom)
}
```

I don't know why that works though.

Example of a ScrollView that stays scrolled at the bottom when the size changes:

```
struct ScrollViewPinnedBottom<Content:View>: View {

    @Namespace var bottomID
    @Namespace var topID

    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content

    @StateObject private var model = ScrollViewPinnedBottomModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { reader in
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack {
                    Color.clear
                        .frame(height: .zero)
                        .id(topID)

                    content()
                    
                    Color.clear
                        .frame(height: .zero)
                        .id(bottomID)
                }
                .readSize { size in
                    if model.shouldScroll(newSize: size) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            reader.scrollTo(topID, anchor: .top)
                            reader.scrollTo(bottomID, anchor: .bottom)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


class ScrollViewPinnedBottomModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var lastSize: CGSize?

    func shouldScroll(newSize: CGSize) -> Bool {
        guard newSize.height != lastSize?.height else { return false }
        lastSize = newSize
        return true
    }

}
```

This example uses this [readSize](https://gist.github.com/zntfdr/f735039b13265d7b25099f524e2116d9) extension.